# How to change WordPress Login URL without Plugin

Tags: wordpress

I am trying to change the wordpress Admin Login URL (wp-admin) by plugin and it will work good. But can't change wordpress theme option. So, any one Please give good solution. and without Plugin. Also want easy way.

Comment: Welcome to SO. This site is not a code-writing service and is not meant for delivering complete solutions. Users are expected to show some effort and code whilst SO is here to help you solve specific programming problems along the way. Have you tried anything already? Please read: https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking

Answer (score 1):

You can try this code.

This code redirects to the homepage whenever the default /wp-admin or /wp-login is accessed. You can set a passcode as the login URL and only allow wp-admin and wp-login access via this URL: https://www.yourdomain.com/?you-set-your-passcode

Add this code to the **functions.php** of your theme.

```
// define and set passcode that serves as login url.
define('PASSCODE','make-you-own-passcode');
```

```
function mask_login_url(){
  // redirect to login page when passcode is verified
  if( !is_user_logged_in() && parse_url($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], PHP_URL_QUERY) == PASSCODE ){
    wp_safe_redirect( home_url('wp-login.php?'. PASSCODE .'&redirect=false') );
    exit();
  }
  // redirect to dashboard if user has already logged in
  if( is_user_logged_in() && parse_url($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], PHP_URL_QUERY) == PASSCODE ){
    wp_safe_redirect( home_url("wp-admin") );
    exit();
  } }
add_action( 'init', 'mask_login_url');

function mask_login_redirects(){
  if( isset($_POST['passcode']) && $_POST['passcode'] == PASSCODE) return false;

  // redirects to dashboard when /wp-admin is accessed and user is logged in
  if ( (is_user_logged_in()) && (strpos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], 'wp-admin') !== false)) {
    wp_safe_redirect( home_url("wp-admin"), 302 );
    exit();
  }
  // redirects to homepage when /wp-admin or /wp-login is accessed and user is not logged in
  if ( (!is_user_logged_in()) && ((strpos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], 'wp-admin') !== false) || (strpos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], 'wp-login') !== false)) && ( strpos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], PASSCODE) === false ) ) {
    wp_safe_redirect( home_url(), 302 );
    exit();
  }
  // redirect to homepage after logout
  if( strpos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], 'action=logout') !== false ){
    check_admin_referer( 'log-out' );
    wp_logout();
    wp_safe_redirect( home_url('?logged-out'), 302 );
    exit();
  } 
}
add_action( 'login_init', 'mask_login_redirects', 1);

// Add a passcode hidden field to login form
function custom_login_hidden_field(){
  echo '<input type="hidden" name="passcode" value="'. PASSCODE .'" />';
}
add_action('login_form', 'custom_login_hidden_field');
```

Answer (score 0):

There are several url's to get to the WP login/admin screen, so you need to change all of them. The below could be DRY-er for sure, but it's broken down into individual solutions. Everything redirects to home_url() except for desired login url:

```
// Disable Password Reset URL & Redirect.
function disable_register_and_lost_pwd_actions() {
  if (isset( $_GET['action'] )){
    if ( in_array( $_GET['action'], array(
      'lostpassword',
      'retrievepassword',
      'register'
    ) ) ) {
      wp_safe_redirect( esc_url(home_url(), 302 ));
      exit;
    }
  }

  if (isset( $_GET['registration'] )){
    if ( in_array( $_GET['registration'], array(
      'enabled',
      'disabled'
    ) ) ) {
      wp_safe_redirect( esc_url(home_url(), 302 ));
      exit;
    }
  }
}
add_action( "login_init", "disable_register_and_lost_pwd_actions" );
```

Below based on this solution:
https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/160098/change-login-url-without-plugin

Whatever you define as the variable $new_login is will be the new login slug:
[www.your-website.com/](http://www.your-website.com/)
or
[www.your-website.com/wp-login.php](http://www.your-website.com/wp-login.php)?

```
function redirect_to_new_login() {
  $new_login = '<your-new-login-here>';
  if (parse_url($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], PHP_URL_PATH) == '/'.$GLOBALS['new_login']) {
    wp_safe_redirect(esc_url(home_url("wp-login.php?{$GLOBALS['new_login']}")));
    exit();
  }
}
add_action('init', 'redirect_to_new_login');

function redirect_old_login_to_home() {
  $new_login =  '<your-new-login-here>';
  if (strpos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], $new_login) === false) {
    wp_safe_redirect(home_url(), 302);
    exit();
  }
}
add_action('login_head', 'redirect_old_login_to_home');
```

Answer (score -2):

I have two recomendations for you.

1 - https://www.elegantthemes.com/blog/tips-tricks/how-to-create-a-custom-wordpress-login-url

2 - This plugin has the option to rename the admin url.
https://www.icontrolwp.com/blog/wordpress-shield-security-plugin/

Regards,
Ed.